Control which Chrome to use
I am running webdriverio in kubernetes. How can I make webdriverio use whatever the local version of the chromedriver is on the system and not download the latest version?
I have tried setting the binary in the wdio.conf.js file.
capabilities: [{ 
     // capabilities for local browser web tests browserName: 'chrome', 
     // or "firefox", "microsoftedge", "safari" 
     'goog:chromeOptions': { 
        args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--disable-infobars', '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1440,735' ], }, 
     binary: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable' 
    }]

